# Flutter - Can't run profile mode in emulator

Tags: ios, flutter

When I run Profile mode in emulator for my flutter projects. this error happens

[image]

This is complete error message if i use --verbose

[image]

Here's my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 3.3.2 on channel stable at /Users/prima/fvm/versions/stable
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e3c29ec00c (3 weeks ago), 2022-09-14 08:46:55 -0500
    • Engine revision a4ff2c53d8
    • Dart version 2.18.1
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/prima/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.48.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • 08082184-3CF4-4E36-A3D4-73BB91B696DA • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 (simulator)
    • iPhone 11 (mobile)         • BFBBDCF6-254F-4F84-9E46-BDA5C9995C0D • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 105.0.5195.125

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I've been looking for a solution and tried several ways but still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Profile mode is disabled to running in emulators and simulators. If you would like to test anything in this mode you need a physical device.